# Convert 12bit to 16bit geoTIFF

Tags: convert, remote-sensing, geotiff-tiff, bit-depth

I just bought some SPOT6/7 satellite imagery. This material has a 12bit format, however, the software I have to import it to just accepts 8, 16 or 32 bit files.

How can I convert my geoTIFF files to 16 bit without loosing the geo-ref.?

Comment: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Comment: What software are you using that won't accept 12 bit?

Answer (score 3):

You don’t have 12bit GeoTiffs, you have 16bit GeoTiffs that store data with values from 0-4095 (12bit range).

See [Pléiades and SPOT 6/7 Format Delivery](http://www.intelligence-airbusds.com/en/3030-pleiades-and-spot-6-7-format-delivery):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to rescale the dynamic range from 12-bit to 16-bit, I would recommend using the scale parameter within gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -scale <min_val> <max_val> 0 65535 <src.tif> <dest.tif>
```

This will reassign the maximum value of your image to 65535 and your minimum value of your image to 0.  This will stretch the image to the full 16-bit dynamic range, which may not be ideal for your application because it can overstretch the image.  A pretty quick workaround is:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -scale <min_val> <max_val> 0 65535 -exponent 0.5 <src.tif> <dest.tif>
```

This will multiply all bands by x^0.5 after the values are scaled.  This will produce a more realistic image with more realistic values while skewing the values closer to the full 16-bit dynamic range.  This approach is commonly used in color correction of imagery when changing between radiometric resolutions, as it creates a more photo-realistic image.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you need to change the format of a raster image [`gdal_translate`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) is the answer you are looking for. In this case it is simply

```
gdal_translate -ot Int16 src.tif dest.tif
```

There are plenty of other output types if your data is not an integer.