# Translating GeoTIFF to 16-bit PNG with GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, png

I have a GeoTIFF file which displays the following information when running `gdalinfo`:

```
Band 1 Block=10012x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = Layer_1
  Min=1638.991 Max=2577.040
  Minimum=1638.991, Maximum=2577.040, Mean=2063.003, StdDev=185.546
  NoData Value=-3.4028234663852886e+038
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=34427.3350382379
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=2577.0400390625
    STATISTICS_MEAN=2063.0031636173
    STATISTICS_MEDIAN=0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1638.9908447266
    STATISTICS_MODE=0
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=185.54604560119
```

Based on this information, I understand that the minimum and maximum grayscale values are `1638.991` and `2577.040` respectively.

What I want to do is convert this GeoTIFF to a 16-bit PNG image which shows ~938 (2577-1638) different shades of gray. I'm attempting to achieve this with the following `gdal_translate` command:

```
"c:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal_translate.exe" -outsize 4096 4096 -of PNG -ot UInt16 -scale 1638.991 2577.040 0 65535 "GDAL_IMG_2_GeoTIFF.tif" "GDAL_IMG_2_GeoTIFF.png"
```

My understanding here is that `-ot UInt16` allows me to create a 16-bit image and `-scale 1638.991 2577.040 0 65535` re-maps the geoTIFF grayscale range to the full 16-bit range (0 - 65535).

This command does indeed produce what appears to be a 16-bit image however when viewing the image properties in irfanView, the `Number of unique colors` is showing as 256.

Full bit-depth info:

[image: irfanView output]

Is there any step that I have missed here for creating 16-bit PNG's which make use of > 256 shades of gray or perhaps a better method?

Comment: Relevant post with similar unsolved issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213111/how-do-i-export-a-16-bit-image-from-qgis

Comment: What does gdalinfo say? What role does IrfanView play here? Maybe IrfanView has to reduce the bitdepth internally to be able to display it? Trust GDAL rather than that..

Comment: Gdalinfo - hist shows you more info about the histogram.

Comment: See onakua's answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230960/convert-12bit-to-16bit-geotiff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took bugmenot123's advice and trusted the GDAL output rather than IrfanView which seems to have issues accurately showing bit depth. I double checked the PNG images in QGIS which showed the correct 16-bit range.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should update your gdal.  Using version 2.4.0 I can generate 16bit PNGs with this command:

```
$ gdal_translate -of PNG -ot UInt16 -scale 32.53501 767.4913 0 65535 goes16.abi-2019.0902.1510-C01_1km.tif k.png

$ pngcheck k.png
OK: k.png (2574x1591, 16-bit grayscale, non-interlaced, 35.0%).
```

The original data is Float32.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at *convert.py* module [here](https://github.com/mohammadreza-sheykhmousa/Geo-tools/tree/main/src/main)

```py
import os
from osgeo import gdal

def geotiff_to_png(input_path, output_path=None, return_object=False):
    """
    Converts a GeoTIFF file to a PNG file or object. Specific to Skysatimages with 4 bands (blue, green, red, nir).

    Args:
        input_path (str): The file path of the input GeoTIFF file.
        output_path (str, optional): The file path of the output PNG file. If not provided, PNG object is returned. Defaults to None.
        return_object (bool, optional): Whether to return the PNG data as an object. If True, the output_path parameter will be ignored. Defaults to False.

    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray or None: If output_path is not provided and return_object is True, returns a 3D numpy array representing the PNG image. Otherwise, returns None.

    """
    # Open input file
    dataset = gdal.Open(input_path)
    output_types = [gdal.GDT_Byte, gdal.GDT_UInt16, gdal.GDT_Float32]
    
    # Define output format and options
    options = gdal.TranslateOptions(format='PNG', bandList=[3,2,1], creationOptions=['WORLDFILE=YES'], outputType=output_types[0])
    
    # Translate to PNG
    if output_path is not None:
        gdal.Translate(output_path, dataset, options=options)
        print(f'Successfully saved PNG file to {output_path}')
    
    # Return PNG object
    if return_object:
        mem_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM')
        mem_dataset = mem_driver.CreateCopy('', dataset, 0)
        png_data = mem_dataset.ReadAsArray()
        return png_data
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).